# Can I change the text color of .gitnore files in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have the following issue.

I am working on a project with multiple    git repositories.

These repositories are excluded from the client    specific data via a .gitnore file.

In netbeans the ignored filenames are    greyed out.

This is useful but the grey color is impractical.

The    file names are near invisible in the tabs.

I still need to edit these    files and commit them to their own repositories but the color makes    it really difficult to see what file i am working on.

I have no    experience what so ever with netbeans theme templating and was hoping    someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind,

Just found it.

In Settings under fonts & Colors there is a Versioning tab.

Click on git then ignored.

You can set the color there.